# What is the name of this visual drawing puzzle made of simple lines and shapes?

Tags: visual, puzzle-identification

I have seen puzzles that are drawn visuals. Someone told me that it involves deciphering the image and finding the meaning. Here's 3 examples of it:

[image: house with a pig tail coming out]

[image: question mark missing dot]

[image: vertical lines, circles and Xs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Droodles](https://www.rd.com/list/roger-price-droodles/), created by comedian Roger Price. They're not puzzles so much as jokes - the "answers" are supposed to make you laugh rather than be genuinely figured out.

Answer (score 2):

The generic term for this picture puzzle type is [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus).

Even though these particular pictures may have been intended as silly picture jokes, there are perfectly reasonable rebus solutions for the first two at least:

[image: house with a pig tail coming out]

> Spring is just around the corner

[image: question mark missing dot]

> A pointless question